# Limit available panes in the Views UI

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm trying to configure the Views UI so that users can only see specific panes (i.e. only fields, filters and style settings panes). I tested [SimpleViews](http://drupal.org/project/simpleviews) and [Views UI: Edit Basic Settings](http://drupal.org/project/views_ui_basic) modules, but it wasn't so useful.

Hiding panes with jQuery was also not a good way.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. On SO, it is considered to be good practice to show what you have already tried on your own to solve the problem (e.g. by showing some code), so that other users become more inclined to help you with your problem.